# custom listview to show notification

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
}

public List<String> getText(Notification notification) {
    if (null == notification) {
        return null;
    }
    RemoteViews views = notification.bigContentView;
    if (views == null) {
        views = notification.contentView;
    }
    if (views == null) {
        return null;
    }
```

How to put this code in android list view 
to show notifications in list.
also provide xml layout for it.

Comment: Did you even try to do it yourself?`How to create a basic list view in android (with xml) can be found in various tutorials, for example here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial

Answer (score -1):

First create a XML file *my_list_view.xml* for your simple ListView like this

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

Then create another xml file *row_view.xml* which will be the layout of each row in your ListView

```
 <RelativeLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:padding="10dp">
         <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/title"
                 android:textSize="25sp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
          <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/subTitle"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Your next step is to create a CustomAdapter to properly inflate your ListView with notifications

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
String titles[];
String subTitles[];
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] titles, String[] subTitles)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.titles = titles;
    this.subTitles=subTitles;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titles.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.row_view, null);
    Textview tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    Textview tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
    tv1.setText(titles[i]);
    tv2.setText(subTitles[i]);
    return view;
}
```

}

and finally in your *MainActivity.java* do the following

```
    String notTitles[] = YOUR_NOTIFICATION_TITLES;
    String notSubTitles[]=YOUR_NOTIFICATION_SUBTITLES;
    ListView simpleList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), notTitles, notSubTitles);
    simpleList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

that's it. :)